# R Function Query

Tags: r, function

Write a function called "query". It takes five inputs

- "age_low": default value = 1
- "age_high": default value = 100
- "keyword":  default value = ""
- "rating_low":  default value = 1
- "rating_high":  default value = 5

and returns a data frame which contains the rows of df where the reviewer's age is between "age_low" and "age_high" (inclusive),the review text contains "keyword" (case insensitive), and the rating is  between "rating_low" and "rating_high" (inclusive).
Save the output of query(age_low=20, age_high=50) in df1
Save the output of query(rating_high=3) in df2
Save the output of query(age_low=20, age_high=50, keyword="price", rating_low=4, rating_high=5) in df3

```
query <- function(age_low=1, age_high=100, keyword="", rating_low=1, rating_high=5) {
  return(df$Age>= age_low and df$Age<=age_high,
         tolower(df$`Review Text` == tolower(keyword)),
         df$Rating>=rating_low and df$Rating<=rating_high)
}

df1 <- query(age_low=20, age_high=50)
df2 <- query(rating_high=3) 
df3 <- query(age_low=20, age_high=50, keyword="price", rating_low=4, rating_high=5)
```

Comment: Is there a question that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Yes I typed it in the beginning. I am having an issue with the query function

Comment: Could you provide example dataframe that this query would be run on?

Comment: what do u mean? im running in R console

Comment: I think what was being asked (by anonymouscoward) is what is the problem that you see with the code you have. Casually at least it looks like you have coded a solution. (SO is not a code review site. We don't function as a staging area for homework problems for which  you have already developed code, unless of course you can identify a problem that needs to be solved.) I will note that "and" is not a legitimate R function and the code does throw an error because of that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the criteria, you should also put `df` as an input for your function as a good habit.

```
query <- function(df=df, age_low=1, age_high=100, keyword="", rating_low=1, rating_high=5) {
  # first filter
  out_df <- df[df$Age>=age_low & df$Age<=age_high, ]

  # second filter
  out_df <- out_df[tolower(out_df$`Review Text`) == tolower(keyword), ]

  # third filter
  out_df <- out_df[out_df$Rating>=rating_low & out_df$Rating<=rating_high, ]

  return(out_df)
}

df1 <- query(age_low=20, age_high=50)
df2 <- query(rating_high=3) 
df3 <- query(age_low=20, age_high=50, keyword="price", rating_low=4, rating_high=5)
```